# Spring Restful issue with list of length 1

Tags: spring, list, rest

We are having a json which shows a list of object as below:

```
skillCheckAnswers: [
{
optionId: 6786,
optionText: "Copy constructor",
optionWeight: "1.00"
},
{
optionId: 6787,
optionText: "Friend constructor",
optionWeight: "2.00"
},
{
optionId: 6788,
optionText: "Default constructor",
optionWeight: "3.00"
},
{
optionId: 6789,
optionText: "Parameterized constructor",
optionWeight: "4.00"
}
]
```

Which is ok as long as there are more than 1 object in the list. But if the list contains only 1 item then the json displays :

```
{
optionId: 6785,
optionText: "Friend class",
optionWeight: "4.00"
}
```

Please note that the second Json is not given as a List but as a single object ( missing square braces[] ).

Is there a way where I can output the list of length 1 with square braces?

Edit--
We can use foreach for the first JSON but foreach starts giving error if the number of object goes to 1. To handle this we are having an if else loop to check if the List is of length 1 or more than 1. If the list is of length then we handle this as a single obkect. This seems to be a stupid solution and I guess there would be an easy way out.

Can anyone tell me if this is even possible?

Comment: How do you create the output? Do you use JAXB to serialize a List?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

From Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/myquestions")
public @ResponseBody
List<Answer> generateQuestions() {

  List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
  Answer ans1 = new Answer();
  ans1.setOptionId("6785");
  ans1.setOptionText("Friend class");
  ans1.setOptionWeight("4.00");
  answers.add(ans1);

  return answers;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[
   {
       "optionId": "6785",
       "optionText": "Friend class",
       "optionWeight": "4.00"
   }
]
```

So far I understood, you problem is related to JSON converter. I have tested with Spring MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter message converter. You can see Spring documentation for how to configure the JSON converter. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you use Spring. Doesn't Spring automatically look after JSON conversions for your the restful API it provides. You can put something like this is your conext file:

You can use [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html) and set it up in your context file to do the JSON conversion for you.

Then you can use Spring MVC's @ResponseBody annotation to provide a restful service with having to handcode the JSON response.

Comment: I can explain more if you tell us 1. Who and How is the restful service (the data above) is provided? i.e. is it a Spring MVC controller using @ResponseBody annotation. 2. How is it consumed / called?

Comment: sorry I am new to webservices so dont know much...I am using @GET and @produces(application/json) .. In applicationcontext.xml I have given: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider

Comment: If you are consistently returning a collection from the Java side then it should be consistently returned as a JSON array.  My suspicion is that you are returning a single element (rather than a 1-element collection) and therefore it is being serialized as such.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am returning a collection(array list) even for a single element